# Facing io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null while consuming server sent events

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am new to spring web flux, I have a client application that consumes server-sent events, The events are published by the server randomly there is not fixed delay. But consumer throws `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null` after 60 secs if there no event

Server-side events consumer code

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("http://localhost:8080/events")
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(type)
        .subscribe(event -> process(event));
```

I need the client to be connected even if there is no event for a long time.

Full Exception

```
[36mr.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect   [...] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null

reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1    onError(org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException)
reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1     

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [Mozilla description for server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format) there is a note:

> A colon as the first character of a line is in essence a comment, and
> is ignored. **Note:** The comment line can be used to prevent connections
> from timing out; a server can send a comment periodically to keep the
> connection alive.

So periodically sending comments can keep the connection alive. So how do we send a comment?

Well spring has the class [ServerSentEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/ServerSentEvent.html) that has the function [ServerSentEvent#comment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/ServerSentEvent.html#comment--). So if we use this class in combination with for instance [Flux#interval](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#interval-java.time.Duration-) we can merge in events containing only the comments `keep alive`.

Here is an example from a project i built a while back

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> foobars() {
    return route()
            .path("/api", builder -> builder
                .GET("/foobar/{id}", accept(TEXT_EVENT_STREAM), request -> ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                        .header("Cache-Control", "no-transform")
                        .body(Flux.merge(foobarHandler.stream(request.pathVariable("id")),
                                Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(15)).map(aLong -> ServerSentEvent.<List<FoobarResponse>>builder()
                                        .comment("keep alive").build())), new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<List<FoobarResponse>>>(){}))
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Webflux use a default timeout fallback that will eventually show `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null`.
It is possible to prevent this error by passing a custom timeout fallback to the timeout method(s):

```
public final Flux<T> timeout(Duration timeout, @Nullable Publisher<? extends T> fallback);
```

Additionally, you can use methods like *onErrorContinue*, *onErrorReturn*, ... to properly handle exceptions in Flux, example:

```
return webClient.get().uri(url).retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class)
    .timeout(timeout, Mono.error(new ReadTimeoutException("Timeout")))
    .onErrorContinue((e, i) -> {
        // Log the error here.
    });
```

If you want to disable all these logs by default it is possible adding this line into file *application.properties*:

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient=OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the HttpClient response timeout, I just increased it

```
HttpClient.create(...).responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
```